# Reading filename(image) to a string using corona

Tags: corona-sdk

Is there a way to get the filename from image and read it to a string using corona?
I can't find any help regarding this issue.

In example, if I had:

```
local movieTitle = display.newImage("pulpfiction.png")
```

How could I print the image name(pulpfiction.png) or store it in a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImage.html), the `newImage` function produces a [`DisplayObject`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/index.html); looking at the services offered by that object, **there is no way to fetch *where* it came from**, or how it's been built, which is, IMHO, reasonable.

Now you did not mention what you were trying to ultimately achieve, so it is hard to give you an alternative that would be perfect for your situation; but generally, when you *know* you'll need this information again after loading the image, one could go the other way around and store the name associated with the DisplayObject built. Perhaps in an associative array.